# The sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin^n(k)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What is $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin^n(k)?$$
Can you find what is the sum of that series. It is convergent not divergent. What if $k=\frac{\pi}{6}$?

Comment: What do you know about $k$?  About $\sin k$?

Answer (score 1):

If $|\sin k|<1,$

$$S_n=\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\sin k\right)^r=\sin k\cdot\dfrac{1-(\sin k)^n}{1-\sin k}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sin k)^n=0$$

Check if $\sin k=1\iff k=2p\pi+\dfrac\pi2$ where $p$ is any integer

and if $\sin k=-1\iff k=2q\pi-\dfrac\pi2$ where $q$ is any integer

Answer (score 0):

It's a  [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

$S(k) = \frac{sin(k)}{1-sin(k)}$

note that $S(k)$  is not defined for $k = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n$

Answer (score -1):

if you plug $k=\frac{\pi}{6} $ 
$$ \Sigma_{1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2})^n=\\\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+...$$ 
$$s_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+...+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{2^n}\\\frac{1}{2}s_n=  \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space\space \space\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+...+\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \\ \to \\ s_n-\frac{1}{2}s_n=\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\\ \frac{1}{2}s_n=\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \\ \to *2 \\s_n =1 -\frac{1}{2^{n}}\\ \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n=\\\lim_{n \to \infty} 1 -\frac{1}{2^{n}}=1$$